# What sort of iterations does GHC do while compiling patterns?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, ghc

I just wrote a function for making a move in Tic-Tac-Toe. I wanted to push pattern matching. So I wrote 9 `makeAMove` clauses. Each has a Tic-Tac-Toe board with a different space designated by an Empty symbol. It looks something like this.

```
makeAMove [[E,   m12, m13],
           [m21, m22, m23],
           [m31, m32, m33]] X 1 1 = ...
```

This clause would put an X in the upper left corner of the board. X, O, and E are defined as Marks.

```
data Mark = X |  O | E deriving (Eq, Show)
```

When I load the file I get this warning message.

```
warning:
    Pattern match checker exceeded (2000000) iterations in
    an equation for ‘mov1’. (Use -fmax-pmcheck-iterations=n
    to set the maximun number of iterations to n)
```

My question is one of curiosity. What sort of iterations is the pattern matcher doing? And why are so many required?

When I limit the number of clauses to, say, 5 and put the rest in another function that is linked to by a default case, there is no problem.

Comment: That's either a bizarre ghc bug or something really weird in your code. Please include enough code to repro. And what version of ghc are you using?

Comment: Can you post the patterns for `mov1`, which seems to be the binding causing the error?

Comment: This seems clearly related to the pattern exhaustivity checker. Since that part of the compiler has been getting a lot of hacking lately, it's pretty critical to know the GHC version as @jberryman suggested

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a MCVE:

```
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
data T = O | A | B | C | D | E

f :: T -> T -> T -> T -> T -> T -> T -> T -> T -> ()
f O _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ = ()
f _ O _ _ _ _ _ _ _ = ()
f _ _ O _ _ _ _ _ _ = ()
f _ _ _ O _ _ _ _ _ = ()
f _ _ _ _ O _ _ _ _ = ()
f _ _ _ _ _ O _ _ _ = ()
f _ _ _ _ _ _ O _ _ = ()
f _ _ _ _ _ _ _ O _ = ()
f _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ O = ()
```

Result:

```
ExhaustivePattern3.hs:5:5: warning:
    Pattern match checker exceeded (2000000) iterations in
    an equation for ‘f’. (Use -fmax-pmcheck-iterations=n
    to set the maximun number of iterations to n)
```

I guess the checker is trying to generate the counterexamples too eagerly: there are many unmatched patterns, exponentially growing with the number of arguments.

Indeed, after the first match the unmatched cases are

```
A _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
B _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
...
E _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Then after the second one, this expands to:

```
A A _ _ _ _ _ _ _
A ...
A E _ _ _ _ _ _ _
B A _ _ _ _ _ _ _
B ...
B E _ _ _ _ _ _ _
...
E A _ _ _ _ _ _ _
E ...
E E _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

And so on. This grows exponentially.

Comment: Nice (or maybe not so nice) find. Have you made / is there already a ticket open for this?

Comment: @Alec I didn't check. Feel free to check / add it if missing.

Comment: @Alec It looks like [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11822) is the most relevant ticket.

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. That's a good example, similar to (and simpler than) what my code did.

Comment: I was trying the example out, and even if you add a line `f _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ = ()` the same warning is given. I would expect that the patter match check does not kick in in this case. Is that a ghc bug?

Comment: @DamianNadales Hard to tell. I'd tend to call it a bug, but I have no idea if the problem is solvable with an efficient algorithm in the first place.